# How to get current day name from Date.today?

Tags: ruby

How does someone get the name of the day from `Date.today`?

The below should be equal too `"Fri"` or `"Friday"`:

```
Date.today #=> Fri, 20 Nov 2015
```

Comment: checkout http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Date.today.strftime("%A")
```

Comment: Or `"%a"` for the abbreviated name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `#name_of_week_day` method

```
Date.today.name_of_week_day
```